# Accessing methods via OBJECTS vs INHERITANCE

Tags: java, inheritance

Consider this child class :

```
public class Circle extends BasicAreas{

 public static void main(String args[])
 {
    BasicAreas ba = new BasicAreas();
    Circle c = new Circle();
    c.PrintCircleArea(ba);
 }


 void PrintCircleArea(BasicAreas ba)
 {
     System.out.println("Area of circle is : "+areaCircle(3.14));
 }
}
```

and the parent class :

```
class BasicAreas{

    double areaCircle(double radius)
    {
       return 3.14 * radius * radius;
    }

    int areaSquare(int side)
    {
       return side * side;
    }

    int areaRectangle(int len, int breadth)
    {
       return len * breadth;
    }
}
```

Now, i am pretty well confused about this... :

```
System.out.println("Area of circle is : "+areaCircle(3.14));
```

When i `extend` a super-class...i can access the methods of that class without using an `instantiated object` like above....but 
when i do not extend a `class`, i can access its method using an `object` like :

```
System.out.println("Area of circle is : "+ba.areaCircle(3.14)); /* "ba" being object */
```

**So my question** is that when should i prefer using `object`s and when to use `extend` to access other `class methods`...and whats the difference between them on basic level??

learning java...so please go easy...i know the question is pretty dumb, but there is no clear answer....i am also open to possibility that this question might be conceptually wrong too!!!

Comment: The question goes beyond Java. It really is about the concepts of object and class, as defined in object-oriented programming. Are you already familiar with those?

Comment: yes...i am...m just confused over this fact that they `inheritance` and `objects` both provide almost same feature only with slight different way of using it...so which one should be used when??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So my question is that when should i prefer using objects and when to use extend to access other class methods...and whats the difference between them on basic level??

the inheritance represents a is-a relationship. but the composition represents a has-a relationship. you can choose any of these two to solve your problem but to make a good design it is important to choose between the right one.

so inheritance should be used only when a subclass is-a superclass. for example in the above example circle is a basicArea. Otherwise use composition.

you can see this [article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076814/core-java/inheritance-versus-composition--which-one-should-you-choose-.html) or plenty of others avaiable on net to find the differences between these two with example.

Comment: +1 : agreed with @NambiNarayanan......`so inheritance should be used only when a subclass is-a superclass` ...this pretty much clear the doubt plus useful link!! :)

Answer (score 1):

When your class is not in the inheritance hierarchy, then you should use object method. When you extend a class, then the child gets the method by default as if it is its own method. THis is because child class is susbclass of superclass. i.e. In your case, `Circle IS-A BasicAreas`.

When you do not extend the class, then you do not have access to method as long as you instantiate the object.

Comment: @NoobEditor I meant the class hierarchy. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: your answer gives solution to question `what is the difference between the two`....`when should i use which one` still goes unanswered!! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor, when you have inheritance relationship between your classes, then you can directly use methods. But your classes are not related with inheritance then you have to instantiate the class and call methods. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, you are accessing the methods with objects.

> When i extend a super-class...i can access the methods of that class
>   without using an instantiated object like above

This is wrong.

In the first case, you are accessing `areaCircle()` method on instance `c`.

Answer (score 1):

`When A class extends a class` it can access the methods in super class i.e

`double areaCircle(double radius)`

in your case and when you are writing

```
System.out.println("Area of circle is : "+areaCircle(3.14));
```

this statement you are actually using object(`this`) for accessing this method the only point here is you are not creating this object.

this statement will be interpreted like this

```
 System.out.println("Area of circle is : "+this.areaCircle(3.14));
```

so you always need object to access a method until it is not static. Because you can access static methods directly with class name.